# Boto - how do I wait for a background process (e.g. mdadm) to finish before running a new command?

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2, boto, raid

I'm scripting up my amazon deployment, and I haven't managed to automate a step in it.

The step is between setting up RAID (via mdadm) and then installing my db (mongo) on the new mounted directory. This is because I have to wait for mdadm to finish in the background before installing mongo. I know when mdadm is finished by running the following command:

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

When mdadm is still in progress this command will produce a progress indicator e.g.:

```
 Rebuild Status : 2% complete
```

When mdadm is finished this status will be gone.

Does anyone have a clean solution for being able to tell when mdadm is finished, so that the script can run entirely on its own, and then continue on to install mongo once mdadm is done?

At the moment I'm contemplating placing a script of sorts on the box using boto, running the script from boto, and having the script exit once it parses and reads that mdadm is finished...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The script is written in which language ? If it's bash script, you can play with 'cut'.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion - I'll have a look into it - I was thinking bash script, so I don't need to install anything else beforehand!

Will post the script up when I get around to it ;)

Answer (score 5):

I am using:

```
 mdadm --wait /dev/md0
```

Note that the above command will return a non-zero exit status if it did not have to wait...you might need to take that into account in the script.

Comment: Sadly, there's no way to specify timeout.

Comment: @iElectric You may want to take a look at the `timeout` command provided by the GNU `coreutils` package. [Here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) is the man page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so as I said I'll post up my solution (I'm completely new to writing bash scripts, so if you have any advice for improvement I'm all ears!!!)

```
#!/bin/bash

false=1
true=0

function drives_are_ready {
  RAID_INFO=`sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0`
  rebuild_status_line_count=`echo "$RAID_INFO" | grep "Rebuild Status" | wc -l`
  echo `echo "$RAID_INFO" | grep "Rebuild Status"`
  if (( rebuild_status_line_count == 0 )); then
    return $true
  else
    return $false
  fi
}

drives_are_ready
raid_is_finished=$?

while (( raid_is_finished == $false )); do
  echo "RAID isn't finished yet... will check again in 10s"
  sleep 10s
  drives_are_ready
  raid_is_finished=$?
done

echo "RAID is done."
```

I scp the file to my instance, and then chmod and run the script via boto.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to wait for the superblock resynchronization before using the disks, but in my (and I'm sure yours as well) experience, it is a very good idea with ec2 instances.

You could simply check for it in a bash while loop

```
#!/bin/bash

... stuff in your script that doesn't require raid ...

# Pause until mdadm --detail returns nothing
while [[ `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep 'Rebuild Status'` != '' ]] do
  sleep 30
done

echo "Raid superblock resynchronization complete"

... stuff in your script that requires raid synchronization to be complete...
```